# Check if site is HTTPS or HTTP?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Okay so I am making a little chrome extension for my company.
I want them to be alerted if they are entering a NON-Secure HTTP website.

Now I have found this little script:

```js
if (isSecureContext) {
   alert('Browsing is HTTPS');
}
```

So if you run this, you can see it says its HTTPS. But if you go to an HTTP website, I want an alert Browsing is not secured.
I tried the ELSE, statement. But that doesn't work for me.

Could somebody help me to write an else statement or something along those lines that it will alert if you are on Non HTTPS?

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/protocol

Comment: @epascarello I don't see what I could do with that one

Comment: Entering a non-secure site, or entered a non-secure site?  (Do you want the alert *before* they go there, or *after* they get there?)

Comment: @Archer Before entering alerting would be nice.

Comment: Okay - I'll rephrase.  Is after they get there good enough?

Comment: @Archer Yes, doesn't matter if thats the only possible fix.

Comment: In that case, `if(isSecureContext) { alert("secure"); } else { alert("not secure"); }` is what you need.  Copy and paste that in the browser console on different sites to test it.  If it doesn't work in your extension then it's your implementation that's wrong.  This is exactly what `isSecureContext` is for.

Comment: @Archer Thank you so much, it works now I changed the Manifest.json file to match <all_urls>.

Answer (score -2):

else should work

Try Else if() {}

Comment: You're not wrong, but this is a very low quality answer.  If you modified it to include actual working code and explained it then that would change.